# Tigrinya language support in iPad / iOS

Tags: ios, fonts, webfonts

We have a website which supports the Tigrinya language, using Arial for normal text. On mobile iOS devices (iPad/iPhone), Tigrinya characters just appear as rectangular boxes.

This problem also appears on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigrinya_language) and [Google](http://www.google.com.et).

Kefa, an iOS font designed specifically to support Ethiopic text, did not work for me when I added the CSS property `font-family: kefa, arial;` to the website.

Comment: On a Mac, you can simply install fonts supporting Tigrinya. No idea about mobile iOS devices though. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3833542

Comment: Kefa is not a font included with iOS. For the current list, check http://iosfonts.com/.

Comment: thanks for the comments guys. Since mine is a website for which i need the font, installing the font on the Mac is not the option for me. 

@LeoNatan thanks for the font list. I am kinda close to a solution. will update about it soon.

Answer (score 3):

### Not possible

Ethiopic is not a supported language on iOS devices. This has been an issue for quite some time and there are numerous references on SO.

### Workaround?

A common workaround would be to install a custom keyboard, which usually comes with an [Apple-certified](http://blog.ethiocloud.com/post/ios-verified-ethiopic-font) font attached to it. An example for this would be the `Abyssinica Ethiopic Font`, which will ship along a keyboard by [EthioCloud](http://blog.ethiocloud.com/post/ethiopic-keyboard-standard-for-smart-phones):

> Ethiopic Keyboard can provide Ethiopic font for devices which do not have built in Ethiopic fonts like iOS systems. The font payload should be a separate installation from the keyboard installation. This gives opportunity to users to change fonts without affecting the keyboard app. Use Unicode compatible Ethiopic font, and your program codes should be Unicode compatible.

Another option is [Keyman 1.1](http://blog.tavultesoft.com/2013/12/keyman-11-eliminates-square-boxes-from-your-iphone-and-ipad.html), which uses the [Geez](http://geezsoft.com/) font for iOS.

**Best solution**

All questions about this in apple forums seem to remain [unanswered](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3863760?tstart=0). I think it would be best to just link this free (mobile) Safari extension from the [AppStore](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/amharic-reader-read-amharic/id932055128?mt=8) on your website.

Comment: Well mines a website. So getting a keyboard installed is something that  a user would need to do. what if he doesnt. Well i did try geez font, but it dint work. Linking it to the free safari extension is a good idea as a fallback  plan. How ever i am just exploring another font, which is feel cud be a solution. I will share the solution today if it works. [I feel a bit positive about this :) ]

Comment: Thanks for the tip. and sorry for the late reply :)

Well i used the font used on the KeyMan website if its IOS. http://s.keyman.com/font/deploy/wookianos.ttf

Comment: This free webfont works well: http://software.sil.org/abyssinica/download/ Albeit, it's not as beautiful as what's rendered on all other systems when NONE of the specified fonts work (MacOS seems to fall back to Kefa regular, which renders beautifully). Is there a way to make the webfont load only when required – in any other way than to try to sniff for iOS?

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the CSS3 `@font-face` rule? http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_fonts.asp

Example code (from the link above):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}

div {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

Comment: This is the best work. I used Nyala font for Microsoft and this method it worked perfectly. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to have Tigriyna rendered on Safari/Chrome/etc on devices with iOS 8.2+

Just install DroidSansEthiopic on your device. Other fonts (e.g. Ebrima, Nyala, Kefa) would also work (modulo copyright issues). DroidSansEthiopic is an Apache licensed font.

1. Go to this page using Safari on your iPad/iOS - https://app.box.com/s/p32l8auh37fo6xnglgd6
2. Click download
3. Follow the steps to install a new Profile.

Tigrinya should be rendered on your Safari.